# How can I set the image Loader correct (SwiftUI)?

Tags: image, swiftui, storage, profile

I'm currently working on a ProfilImagePicker and it all works, but I've also built in a storage system and that works too.
But my problem is, when I select a photo it is not set immediately, but only when I reload the page completely, or when I insert a new image, then only the first one is inserted.

I hope someone can help me.

Storage system

```
class AppStorageHelperProfilImage: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedImage: UIImage?

    static func saveProfileImage(_ image: UIImage) {
        if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0) {
            do {
                try data.write(to: profileImagePath)
            } catch {
                print("Fehler beim Speichern des Profilbilds: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    }

    static func loadProfileImage() -> UIImage? {
        if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: profileImagePath) {
            return UIImage(data: data)
        }
        return nil
    }

    static func deleteProfileImage() {
        do {
            try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: profileImagePath)
        } catch {
            print("Mistake by saving the picture \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }

    private static var profileImagePath: URL {
        FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("profileImage.jpg")
    }
}
```

My Variables

```
@StateObject private var appStorageHelper = AppStorageHelperProfilImage()

@State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
   private var profileImage: UIImage? {
       AppStorageHelperProfilImage.loadProfileImage()
    }
@State private var isProfileImagePickerPresented = false
```

The Image

```
Image(uiImage: profileImage ?? {
                            let symbolImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
                            let imageRenderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 120, height: 120))

                            return imageRenderer.image { _ in
                                symbolImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120))
                            }
                        }())
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
                        .clipShape(Circle())
                        .onTapGesture {
                            isProfileImagePickerPresented.toggle()
                        }
                        .id(appStorageHelper.selectedImage)
                        .sheet(isPresented: $isProfileImagePickerPresented) {
                            ProfileImagePicker(selectedImage: $appStorageHelper.selectedImage, isImagePickerPresented: $isProfileImagePickerPresented)
                                .onDisappear {
                                    // Aktualisieren Sie die Ansicht, wenn das Bild ausgewählt wurde
                                    appStorageHelper.selectedImage.map { saveProfileImage($0) }
                                }
                        }
                        .padding()
```

Profil Image Picker

```
struct ProfileImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @Binding var isImagePickerPresented: Bool

    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ProfileImagePicker

        init(parent: ProfileImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }

        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = selectedImage
            }
            parent.isImagePickerPresented = false
        }

        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            parent.isImagePickerPresented = false
        }
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }

    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ProfileImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }

    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ProfileImagePicker>) {
        // Update UI if needed
    }
}
```

Mini Version

```
Image(uiImage: (selectedImage ?? UIImage(systemName: "person.circle"))!)
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFill()
                                .frame(width: 50, height: 50)
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .id(appStorageHelper.selectedImage)
                                .onAppear {
                                    if selectedImage == nil {
                                        if let loadedImage = AppStorageHelperProfilImage.loadProfileImage() {
                                            selectedImage = loadedImage
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                .padding()
```

Comment: What are those lines below 'My Variables'?  They don't belong to a class or a struct?

Comment: For the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick solution would be to set this line like this:

`Image(uiImage: appStorageHelper.selectedImage ?? // Rest of the code as it was here`.

The issue is that the profileImage does not redraws the UI since it cannot be a State varibale due to the fact it is a computed property.
The other solution would simply be to update the selectedImage variable once you select the new image. For that I've added a callback to the ProfileImagePicker struct like so:

```
struct ProfileImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @Binding var isImagePickerPresented: Bool
    
    /// Add this callback
    var onImageChosen: (UIImage?) -> Void
    
    class Coordinator: NSObject, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {
        var parent: ProfileImagePicker
        
        init(parent: ProfileImagePicker) {
            self.parent = parent
        }
        
        func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey: Any]) {
            if let selectedImage = info[.originalImage] as? UIImage {
                parent.selectedImage = selectedImage
                /// Call the callback here and pass it the new chosen image
                parent.onImageChosen(selectedImage)
            }
            parent.isImagePickerPresented = false
        }
        
        func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
            parent.isImagePickerPresented = false
        }
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(parent: self)
    }
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ProfileImagePicker>) -> UIImagePickerController {
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIImagePickerController, context: UIViewControllerRepresentableContext<ProfileImagePicker>) {
        // Update UI if needed
    }
}
```

And then update the rest of your code like this:

```
@StateObject private var appStorageHelper = AppStorageHelperProfilImage()

@State private var selectedImage: UIImage?
private var profileImage: UIImage? {
    AppStorageHelperProfilImage.loadProfileImage()
}
@State private var isProfileImagePickerPresented = false

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Image(uiImage: selectedImage ?? {
            let symbolImage = UIImage(systemName: "person.circle")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
            let imageRenderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 120, height: 120))
            
            return imageRenderer.image { _ in
                symbolImage?.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 120, height: 120))
            }
        }())
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 120, height: 120)
        .clipShape(Circle())
        .onTapGesture {
            isProfileImagePickerPresented.toggle()
        }
        .id(appStorageHelper.selectedImage)
        .sheet(isPresented: $isProfileImagePickerPresented) {
            ProfileImagePicker(selectedImage: $appStorageHelper.selectedImage, isImagePickerPresented: $isProfileImagePickerPresented) { image in
                withAnimation {
                    selectedImage = image
                }
            }
            .onDisappear {
                // Aktualisieren Sie die Ansicht, wenn das Bild ausgewählt wurde
                //appStorageHelper.selectedImage.map { saveProfileImage($0) }
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Hey,

unfortunately it only works partially, so the main problem is now solved, thank you very much for that, but it is no longer saved or loaded in the AppStorageHelperProfilImage.

Comment: Uncomment the line where it saves it, no? I could not use because it wasn't there.

Comment: Ok, maybe I get what your problem is now. You could use the .onAppear to load the image into the selectedImage state variable. Let me know if that works, and please, if my answer was useful, consider at least upvoting it.

Comment: Thank you very much, that helped me a lot.

I now wanted to create a small version of the profile picture in another struct (the same but smaller) and that almost works, but it is not updated immediately, maybe you can help me with that too.

Comment: Yes, sure. Show me the code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256786/discussion-between-jojowho44-and-matbuompy).